# C++ (Pointers,Filehandling,Classes)

Tags: class, pointers

Can someone recommend me any channel or any videos page to learn pointers/file handling/classes more deeply and thoroughly must be in C++.
-thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, if I was new with C++, I would spend time reading end-to-end [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321543726) from B. Stroustrup.

You can read directly the chapters you need now. However, in order to start a professional journey to C++, you will need to read the whole thing (or equally dense ones).

I do not think that a video will be complete enough.

Comment: Basically, I am not a total beginner, I mean most of the stuff till OOP in C++ but some of the concepts like if we upgrade our pointers to 4d instead of 1d Pointer than it confuses me a lot... so is there any way through which I can clear my confusion related to pointers? or is it just reading the book that can help me out?